# Display shortcode if attachments exist

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a custom media center wordpress website.

I have created my own gallery, which I insert into my template via this...

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery customgal="true"]'); ?>
```

But however, on occasions, sometimes my post will have other attachments besides just images.

So I have added this shortcode, using the [EG Attachments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/eg-attachments/) plugin, which adds other attachments into my post...

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[attachments]'); ?>
```

This works fine. But above my attachment shortcode, I need a H tag title...

```
<h2>Videos</h2>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[attachments]'); ?>
```

But my problem is, if no attachments have been added to my post, then I'm stuck with a title and nothing below it!

Is it possible to only display my shortcode if attachments, other than images, exist?

Something like this...

```
<?php if (attachmentexists()) { ?>

     <h2>Other Attachments</h2>

     <?php echo do_shortcode('[attachments]'); ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea. The best solution here would probably be to assign the result of `<?php echo do_shortcode('[attachments]'); ?>` to a variable, and then check to see if it's set:

```
<?php $attachments = do_shortcode('[attachments]'); ?>
<?php if( $attachments ): ?>
    <h2>Videos</h2>
    <?php echo $attachments; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Alternatively, you can amend your shortcode to take a parameter, e.g. title `[attachments title="Videos"]`, and perform the (same) logic from within the shortcode.

Comment: Thanks Chris, worked a beaut :-). I've added some comments above in your code if you don't mind answering them please, not quite sure whats happening. Thanks

Comment: Yes -- `$attachments` is assigned on the first line to the result of your shortcode, which I assumed (since you were echo'ing it, although it should be anyway) is a string. There is a bit of "magic" that goes on with the second line, in that `if( $attachments )` converts `$attachments` to a boolean (e.g. true/false). In PHP, empty strings, when casted to boolean, are `false` [see more here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). In short, if your shortcode returns nothing (e.g. an empty string), it will not execute the `if` statement.

Comment: Nice! I understand whats happening. I'll be sure to try out this method the future, now I know what it can do. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your question is yet, but change the way you output your PHP:

```
<?
     if (attachmentexists()) {
     echo "<h2>Videos</h2>";
     echo do_shortcode('[attachments]');
     } 
?>
```

Comment: Sure it works, but its bad formatting and bulky. Adding more characters into the script then necessary.

Comment: I agree it's bad formatting, but really it's personal preference. I prefer the format that I used in my answer. As far as "bulky" -- doesn't matter, as it's all processed server-side anyway.